# Add new function in Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm creating new function in my Google Cloud Function. Whenever I tried to deploy my function, error "Failed to retrieve function source code" come out. I know that this error come out from how I call my source code, but I have no idea to call it.

My App function is called in index.js in src folder. However, when I tried to do something like the image below, I get the error.

[image: Fields in Google Cloud Function]

This is my Cloud Source Repositories. As you can see, index.js is in src folder. index.js imports code from App.js.

[image: Google Cloud Repository]

This is the code from my App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

import '@/assets/scss/index.scss';
import theme from '@/theme';
import { USERS, PRODUCTS, CATEGORIES, CLIENTS, MACHINES, TRANSACTIONS } from '@/vars/resources';
import customRoutes from '@/customRoutes';
import { authProvider, dataProvider, i18nProvider } from '@/providers';
import customReducers from '@/redux/reducers';

import AppLayout from '@/layouts/AppLayout';
import { UserList, UserCreate, UserEdit } from '@/pages/users';
import { ProductList, ProductCreate, ProductEdit } from '@/pages/products';
import { CategoryList, CategoryCreate, CategoryEdit } from '@/pages/categories';
import { MachineList, MachineEdit } from '@/pages/machines';
import { TransactionList } from '@/pages/transactions';
import { SignIn } from '@/pages/auth';
import Dashboard from '@/pages/dashboard';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Admin
        theme={theme}
        history={createBrowserHistory()}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
        layout={AppLayout}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        loginPage={SignIn}
        customRoutes={customRoutes}
        customReducers={customReducers}
      >
        <Resource name={USERS} list={UserList} create={UserCreate} edit={UserEdit} />
        <Resource name={PRODUCTS} list={ProductList} create={ProductCreate} edit={ProductEdit} />
        <Resource name={CATEGORIES} list={CategoryList} create={CategoryCreate} edit={CategoryEdit} />
        <Resource name={MACHINES} list={MachineList} edit={MachineEdit} />
        <Resource name={TRANSACTIONS} list={TransactionList} />
        <Resource name={CLIENTS} />
      </Admin>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong here. There's another index.html in my public folder. However, that html file is just an empty HTML file.

Comment: I'm not expert in JS, but your function signature seems not compliant. try to add a req,res as param. In addition, you can have more detail about the error in stackdriver logging. Please share more to understand what happen!

Answer (score 0):

Your cloud function in the `index.js` file has to have the form:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

[Node.js Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs)

Function to execute has to be the same as function name in `index.js`. In my case, the Function to execute will be `helloWorld`. You are trying to execute `App` which does not exist in `index.js`.